# Variables Used for "Find Contour"

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, vector

I a trying to find contours in a video in OpenCV. I have tried to use the sample that is mentioned in OpenCV website and also other samples too.
I have seen in all examples they are using such variable definition:

```
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
```

Would you please let me know what is meaning of these variables in codes?
Also does anybody have a simple code for finding contours in a live video?

Comment: A single contour is made of point, so it's a `vector<Point>`. So `contours` is a vector of contours, each made by a vector of points. Regarding hierarchy, look at the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours). Working on a still image, or a single frame of a video is the same thing. Have a look at [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) example. Also, seriously, try to search better... ton of questions about this stuff

Comment: Thanks Miki,you always give me good advice, to be honest,  am quite new in OpenCV and some concepts of C++, so whenI read the OpenCv documentation and also other guidance I become confused, so I am trying to ask from somebody to tell a simpler form of the concept that I have problem, by the way, I will try to search more in net to find my question's answer, by the way, I appreciate
 your kind attention

Answer (score 0):

from [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours)

> **contours** – Detected contours. Each contour is stored as a vector of points.
>
> **hierarchy** – Optional output vector, containing information about the image topology. It has as many elements as the number of contours. For each i-th contour contours[i] , the elements hierarchy[i][0] , hiearchy[i](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) , hiearchy[i][2] , and hiearchy[i][3] are set to 0-based indices in contours of the next and previous contours at the same hierarchical level, the first child contour and the parent contour, respectively. If for the contour i there are no next, previous, parent, or nested contours, the corresponding elements of hierarchy[i] will be negative.